# Simple Html for Left and right inside container

Tags: html, css

I have created a page which has a container of 350px.
Now I have two sections, one on the left and the other on the right side.
Left content is fixed, whereas the right content is flexible to contain more text.

I have used float:left and float right for left and right positioning. And to get more text I use the word-wrap:break-word.

However, I have to use a div to include the clear class after every point.
Is there a smarter way to do this?

[EDIT] : I know this can be done using the <li> or <table> but I wanted to know if there was a way to get this structure using the div structure itself.

This makes my question easier to understand : http://jsfiddle.net/tKHkS/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the clearer `div`'s

Just `clear:both` on the left questions.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3H6Ue/